# How to download and print with Scalable fonts in a zebra printer

Tags: fonts, zebra-printers, scalable

Does anyone know if it's possible "download" a specific scalable font to the memory of a zebra printer? And if it's possible, how can I do it and how could I write with the downloaded font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZebraNet Bridge will allow you to convert the font to store on your printer, but becareful of licensing issues. Fonts on your PC are usually licensed fonts...

For printing using the font you can reference it with the ^A@ command.

Here is a link that shows how to print Unicode using a downloaded font:

https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6820&actp=RSS